# Ошибка в программе c++

Tags: c++

Привет всем активным участникам этого замечательного форума. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в ошибке.
Задание: *Дано целое число **n**. Вычислить сумму **s=1+1/1!+1/2!+...+1/n!***

В попытках разобраться, как вычислить факториал и запихнуть это вычисление в число вышло это:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float s = 0;
    int predN;
    long int fra = 1; // переменная для записи n!


    cout << "n: ";
    cin >> predN;
    
   
    for (int n = 1; n <= predN; n++) {
        fra = fra * n; // вычисление n!
        s = s + 1 / fra; // сложение чисел s кроме первой единицы 
    }
    s = 1 + s; //прибавление первой единицы к числу
    cout << s; //вывод ответа

    return 0; 

}
```

Но к превеликому сожалению компилятор вместо ответа выдаёт следующее, при этом консоль не появляется и говорит об ошибке сборки.

[image: Вывод программы]

Ошибка где-то есть, возможно в вычислении факториала, однако её поиски оказались тщетны. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Пробовал делать Debug x64 и x86, Visual Studio всё равно выдаёт следующее:
[image: Вывод IDE]

Comment: Ошибка, конечно, есть - вы использовали целочисленное деление `1/fra`, так что толку не будет, получите вы 2 вместо *e*... Ну и еще - для n>12 факториал от n вызовет переполнение значения `long int`...  но это здесь ни при чем.

Comment: А ошибки **компиляции** тут нет. Я только что успешно собрал ваш код с помощью `mingw 8.1`

Comment: На http://cpp.sh/ код тоже нормально компилируется, хотя и выдаёт явно кривые ответы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Всё начало работать при перезагрузке, но выдавало постоянный ответ 2.
После изменения типа переменных на `double` всё заработало и начало давать более-менее правильный ответ.
Вот исправленный код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double s = 0;
    int predN;
    long double fra = 1; // переменная для записи n!


    cout << "n: ";
    cin >> predN;


    for (int n = 1; n <= predN; n++) {
        fra = fra * n; // вычисление n!
        s = s + 1 / fra; // сложение чисел s кроме первой единицы 
    }
    s = 1 + s; //прибавление первой единицы к числу
    cout << s; //вывод ответа

    return 0;

}
```

Спасибо всем, кто комментировал и отвечал. Закрываю вопрос.